# Setting a focus after scanning of barcode is not working sometimes

Tags: java, adempiere

When I am running application on my machine setting of focus on a text field working fine but if same application running from another machine then its not working

I checked the browser setting but both browse are same, Only OS is different

I used callout in adempiere on the text feild

I want set the focus on field after scanning a barcode

Comment: Browser? So... is this really a Java question or rather JavaScript? Also, you might have better chances to get a good answer if you provided some code, here.

Comment: browser Mozilla Firefox

Comment: in Adempiere we use swing

Comment: Could you paste your call-out code here?

Comment: `Not working` what do you mean by not working here? Is it show error or else?

Answer (score 0):

How the browser moves the focus will depend on the scanner you use as well.  The Swing GUI should react to the enter key to bind the scanned data in the field. Then the tab key will move the focus.  You can use the callout for this, but beware what keystrokes the scanner is adding as it may be programmed differently between the two computers.  Rather than writing a callout, it would be easier to program the scanner to enter the required number of tab key hits to get to the field you are targeting.